# Understanding the use of .reduce() in JavaScript code for filtering objects based on matching key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm trying to understand the following JavaScript code that is supposed to filter an array of objects based on matching name and value pairs. The code works, but I'm having trouble grasping the use of the `.reduce()` method at the end. Here's the code:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  const sourceKeys = Object.keys(source);
  return collection.filter(obj => sourceKeys
      .map(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key])
      .reduce((a, b) => a && b));
}
```

The desired functionality is to return an array of objects from collection that have matching name and value pairs with the source object. However, I'm not fully understanding the purpose of the `.reduce()` method in this context.

Why is the `.reduce()` method necessary in this code and how does it contribute to achieving the desired output? I am seeking a detailed explanation of the code logic and the role of `.reduce()` in filtering the objects.

Comment: just a truthy check `function (previousValue, currentValue) { return previousValue && currentValue; }`

Comment: It is not necessary, and it is in fact wrong, causing an error if the `source` object is empty. It should be `sourceKeys.every(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

This use of `reduce()` is effectively equivalent to

```
.every(el => el)
```

Each time through the `reduce()` iteration, it performs a logical AND between the current element `b` and the accumulator `a`. So the final result will be truthy only when all the array elements are truthy.

It's less efficient than `.every()` because the latter can stop iterating as soon as it encounters a falsey element, while `.reduce()` will go through the entire array.

Comment: …and more importantly, `.every` works fine on empty arrays whereas the `.reduce` with missing initial value throws an exception.

Comment: True. `reduce()` should be given an initial value `true`.